# Correlation seen with low billirubin levels but not the gene that causes Gilbert's syndrome

Tags: correlation

I was reading the following study on associations between bilirubin and CAD (coronary artery disease). They looked at the bilirubin association with CAD, and the genes that cause Gilbert's syndrome association with CAD. Gilbert's syndrome is a disease that presents with increased bilirubin concentrations. Study here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2648823/

The study states in the abstract:

> "Both polymorphisms showed a strong association with bilirubin levels with higher levels for homozygote carriers of the minor allele."

But then goes on to say, a few sentences later:

> "Logistic regression analysis revealed low bilirubin levels but not the UGT1A1 polymorphisms to be significantly associated with CAD: OR (95%CI) 0.90 (0.86–0.94), p=2.6×10−6 for men and 0.77 (0.68–0.87), p=3.2×10−5 for women, respectively for each 0.1 mg/dl increase of bilirubin."

How can we see a "strong association" between the gene that causes gilberts sydrome and bilirubin levels but not see an associatoin between the gene and CAD risk? If the study is stating bilirubin is significantly associated with CAD risk, and the polymorphism/gene is **strongly** associated with the level of bilirubin, shouldn't it follow that we would see an association between the polymorphism/gene and CAD?

My guess is that polymorphism correlation to bilirubin levels isnt actually all that strong, or that the association between bilirubin and CAD isnt all that strong, or both. Hoping someone could offer some thoughts on what they think is going on.

Thanks!

Comment: You mght also consider posting this at datamethods.org which is a discussion board where methodologists and subject matter experts meet.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside any caveats about flaws in the methodology itself: strong ***association*** does not necessarily mean strong ***effect***, it just means it's a *reliable* one.

If the expression of that gene was a perfect linear predictor of bilirubin levels, but the slope was 0.0001, it means you'd need an enormous amount of expression to actually see some real difference - but you'd always see it.

If CAD 'cares' only about the bilirubin levels and NOT the genetic background itself, then you will only observe CAD cases on the rise if the genes actually have a serious impact on bilirubin in a patient.

If they just kind of nudge it a little bit, the change in bilirubin levels would get lost in the noise of all the other things that might influence it (compensatory mechanisms, natural swings, other genes' effects). If there is no direct link between what alleles you have and whether you get CAD, this would weaken the association.

Indeed, this seems to be what the authors of the study conclude - bilirubin predicts CAD, but genetic makeup is only linked with CAD indirectly.